# Groupby to find min date with conditions in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have like 3 columns in a data frame for example

`Column_A` has 2 categorical values like A,B

`Column_B` also has 3 categorical values like Type1, Type2, Type3

`Date` column has values like `2010-06-13,2010-06-10`

There are about 20,000 rows so the Categorical Column A,B's values keep repeating.

So  I need the find min date where `Column_A='A' and Column_B='type 1'` using Python(Pandas,Numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean index with `loc` and `min`:

`df.loc[(df['Column_A'] == 'A') & (df['Column_B'] == 'type 1'), 'Date'].min()`